# How to put the figure at top of the second page?

Tags: graphics, floats

I'm trying to write the article which include 2 figures, the first figure is all right at the first page, but when I include second figure, it always at the center of the second page, how to put it at the top of the second page? This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=3]{universe}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=3]{universe}
\caption{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the community of the user of TeX.SE. +1

Comment: The input for a float (figure or table) should occur in the source file *before* any text that will be set on the target page.  But if your figure does get set on the intended page, you should eliminate the `[h]` from the options and leave only `[t]`.  Also, the `!` may be affecting the placement, so I'd be inclined to omit that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to answer without a concrete example. Here I tried to imagine the situation you describe. If you add some text after the second image the position will be correct. You can get the same result with `\pagebreak\null` after the second `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
 
 \section{Introduction}
 
 \begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}
  \caption{The Universe}
  \label{fig:universe}
 \end{figure}
 
 \begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a}
  \caption{The Universe}
  \label{fig:universe}
 \end{figure}

\lipsum
% \pagebreak\null
 
\end{document}
```

With additional text via `\lipsum`:

[image]

With `\pagebrek\null`:

[image]